# File formats not supported by Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, sketchup, media-library, compressed-folder

On a Wordpress site, I would like to make some files available for downloading, and some of these, I've just found out, cannot be added to the media library. Namely, it's not letting me upload a zipped folder, a Sketchup (.skp) file, and an HTML file.

If I want to make files available through a Wordpress site that Wordpress does not support, what are my options? Would it be possible to have a file stored elsewhere and still be downloadable through a link on the Wordpress site? I'm new to Wordpress, but (correct me if I'm wrong) Wordpress.com, where the site in question is hosted, does not seem to allow plugins.

Comment: Host those files somewhere else and link to them from wordpress. It's best to zip HTML, .skp or whatever files and make thus making them available for download.

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress.com is essentially a blogging platform unlike wordpress.org where you can download the wordpress package and install it on a server.Most of blogging service providers wont allow you to upload files to there server due to security issue like Shells and software piracy.

It is better to host your files somewhere else and public link to your blog. Another solution is to buy a hosting account and install wordpress software, where you can upload and store files you need without any restriction.(According to providers usage policies)

Comment: I've looked into a hosting account at some place like Bluehost or Dreamhost, but decided, for the time being, to host the site on Wordpress.com (which was the cheapest option, as far as I could tell). For hosting just two or three files and a compressed folder elsewhere, where would you recommend hosting them (if price is the main consideration and security a somewhat distant second)?

Comment: Sorry for my delayed reply Mhoram.
You can host file in Google Drive,Dropbox,Mediafire etc.. And there in Dropbox you may get simple direct link to that file from other services user need to download it from the download button in that link.